# Joining Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is really simple but I need a quick way to do this.

I have three arrays like

```
$a = array('a','b','c');
$p = array('p','q','r');
$x = array('x','y','z');
```

How do I combine them to make

```
array (
    [0] => array ('a','p','x');
    [1] => array ('b','q','y');
    [2] => array ('c','r','z');
);
```

Comment: i am not sure you can use the same index for different arrays

Comment: @atif089, I changed the indexes from `0` to `0,1,2` because your question seemed to be centered around the values changing and not the three items with the same index.

Comment: yeah I made a mistake in the question there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't `array_map(null, $a, $p, $x);` be better?

See [`array_map`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_map).

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$a = array('a','b','c');
$p = array('p','q','r');
$x = array('x','y','z');

$arr = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
  $arr[$i] = array($a[$i], $p[$i], $x[$i]);
}
?>
```

Comment: I was doing the same lol. i thought tehre might be a better way :)

Comment: there's probably a tricky PHPism that would do it, but whatever... get 'r done, as it were.

Comment: Better use the `min(count($a), count($p), count($x))` to get the largest common index if the arrays do not have the same size.

Comment: arays are always going to be of same size

Answer (score 0):

[`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) is simpler, but for the sake of possibibility, a quickly typed code example to make use of the [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/MultipleIterator) to solve the issue:

```
$it = new MultipleIterator;
foreach(array($a, $p, $x) as $array) {
    $it->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
}
$items = iterator_to_array($it, FALSE);
```

Might be handy in case it's more than an array.