# Creating new two-dimensional PHP Array where keys match

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following three arrays and need to create a new two-dimensional array where the keys match.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Item 0
    [1] => Item 1
    [2] => Item 2
    [3] => Item 3
Array
(
    [0] => £35.00
    [1] => £60.00
    [2] => £24.00
    [3] => £79.00
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
```

I need my new array as follows:

```
$items = Array( 
           Array("Item 0", "£35.00" , 2),
           Array("Item 1", "£60.00" , 1),
           Array("Item 2", "£24.00" , 1),
           Array("Item 3", "£79.00" , 1)
         );
```

I've tried using array_merge, array_merge_recursive, array_combine, $array1+$array2+$array3 but none of them seem to do what I'm after.

Any pointers would be appreciated :) Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining Arrays in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962933/joining-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as all the arrays are the same length, you can use [`array_map`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_map) with `null` as callback

```
print_r(array_map(null,
    $array1, $array2, $array3 
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$items=array();
foreach($array1 as $k=>$v){
$items[]=array($array1[$k],$array2[$k],$array3[$k]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick and was easiest for me to understand :) I'll mark as solved when it lets me in a few minutes. Cheers